# Heroku App Not Compatible with Python Buildpack

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Django/Python application that runs locally, but will not deploy to Heroku. When trying to deploy, I receive the error:

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-
buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
```

I've tried multiple solutions to this issue. Currently my build pack is set to the Python build pack. (heroic build packs returns heroku/python). I have a Procfile, requirements.txt, runtime.txt, and Pipfile.lock, all of which usually resolve this issue.

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn foodForThought.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.11.8
pytz==2017.3
```

runtime.txt:

```
python-3.6.0
```

Pipfile.lock:

```
[requires]
python_full_version = "3.6.0"
```

All the aforementioned files are located in my home directory, and I'm also working in a virtual environment. Why is this error occurring?

Comment: You shouldn't need both a `runtime.txt` file and a `Pipefile.lock` file

Comment: @n8sty Originally I was only using runtime.txt, but couldn't find a solution to the issue. Regardless, neither of them are helping Heroku detect the app's language.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I've come up with. I was also stuck with this problem until I found this command.

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
```

The trick is to **add** this buildpack before you commit to the ***Heroku*** git repo. You can follow the steps like so:

```
git add .
git commit -am "First Commit"
heroku git:remote -a yourapp
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
git push heroku master
```

I found this through the Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)!